# How to login user using rest api in yii2

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I new in yii2, I want login user using rest api but unable to do this.I have setup basic REST API From This blog:

> budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

After that I have created :

> api\modules\v1\controllers\SiteController.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends ActiveController
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\user';    


    public function actionIndex()
    {
            if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

And Created Model

> RtWorkForce\api\modules\v1\models\User.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\models;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * User Model
 *
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';

    }


}
```

Here Is my main.php

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [ 
                'request' => [
                    'parsers' => [
                        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
                    ]
                ],  
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => ['v1/country','v1/user','v1/site'],
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ]

                ]
            ],        
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

But IT's not working i don't know where i am wrong ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Yii 2.0 REST Authentication docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html) :

> Unlike Web applications, RESTful APIs are usually stateless, which
>   means sessions or cookies should not be used.

And from [this other docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html#implementing-identity) about the **user** class which implement **yii\web\IdentityInterface** :

> if your application is a pure stateless RESTful application, you would
>   only need to implement findIdentityByAccessToken() and getId() while
>   leaving all other methods with an empty body.

---

RESTfull is about routing. If following a token based authentication, then, It should return a *resources* or a *collections* if the request sent to server is holding a valid **token**. Otherwise it should be rejected.

Login process in that case, is one request holding a **username/password** pair that will be exchanged with a valid **token** by server, that is the *token* you are going to include with all your next requests.

If **session** is disabled on server side by setting `enableSession` to `false` as described in Yii documentation (*see links above*) and as recommended by the *stateless* nature of REST, then `\Yii::$app->user->isGuest` should not provide info as your server won't have any *session* to get it from. (*unless it verifies token validity instead of checking session*)

When building a class extending [yii\rest\ActiveController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html) you can't render a html page like :

```
return $this->render('login', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

or redirect to a different HTML page like :

```
return $this->goHome();
```

That will work with a [yii\base\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html) when building a HTML based web app instead of [yii\rest\ActiveController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html). with ActiveController you just return data which will be serialized to *json* or *xml* before output.

Please refer to [Yii RESTful API framework documentations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) for more details. Then you may find useful information in this great tutorial on *How to implement Yii2 REST Authentication* :

http://blog.neattutorials.com/angularjs-and-yii2-part-2-authentication/

Comment: I am trying given solution once it will complete let you know.   :)